# Laravel - extending Illuminate\Http\Request and using session

Tags: laravel, session, request, laravel-7

I've extended the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class and am passing it along to my controller.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyRequest extends Request
{
   ...
}
```

Controller

```
class MyController
{
    // Doesnt work
    public function something(MyRequest $request) {
        var_dump($request->session())
    }

   // Does work
    public function something(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        var_dump($request->session())
    }

}
```

So when I'm trying to get session `$request->session()` I get `RuntimeException - Session store not set on request.`

I feel it has something to do with not running middlewares on my custom request but I dont know how to make it work. Helping or pionting to the right direction would be much apreciated.

To give a little bit more info. I'm trying to make a wizard. Several pages where content of one page depends on choices on previous pages. I'm storing the data in session and on the final page I do "stuff" with it and clear the session storage of current user.

Because it a lot of lines of code and since session instace lives on request I though it would be elegant to hide all those line it in custom request and in controler simply call `$myRequest->storeInputs()`

This is what seemed to me as "most elegant" in this particular case so I would prefer to finish it this way but I'm also open to a different solution if there is a better aproach.

Summary: basically where should I hide all those lines which are storing and retriving data from sesison?

Solution: I actually solved it by extending FormRequest since it was solution which was the best fit for what I was trying to do. However I accepted the one offered answer since I believe it is generally better solution and I would use it if not for this very particullar case.

Comment: So you are saying it is fixable if I would do something like $app->alias('request', 'MyRequest') ?;

Comment: Yes. Just wanna add couple methods.

Comment: I though about that but I would much rather extend the class if thats possible?

Comment: Something of that sort?
$request =MyRequest::capture();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

Or I'm still completly off?

Comment: Would be a better solution to extend FormRequest instead?

Comment: I have updated the question to better describe what I'm trying to do. Does it make sense?

Comment: make a different class that "hides" all this and use that class ... that is it ... have fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic Laravel request already got a bunch of settings you didn't catch on your custom request. To achieve that, you should setup a middleware (maybe global in your use-case) which replaces old request in Laravel's container by yours.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Http\MyRequest;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomizeRequest
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * @var \App\Http\MyRequest
     */
    protected $myRequest;

    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @param  \App\Http\MyRequest  $myRequest
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app, MyRequest $myRequest)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->myRequest = $myRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->app->instance(
            'request', Request::createFrom($request, $this->myRequest)
        );

        return $next($this->myRequest);
    }
}
```